# Unix - how to print the difference between two text files?

Tags: shell, unix

I have two files a.unl and b.unl. The content is:

```
#a.unl
300111
302130
300042
300054
400045

#b.unl
200032
300042
300111
565000
310056
```

And then there is c.unl to catch the difference.
If a line from a.unl is a match with a line in b.unl, then it won't print to c.unl. It only print if it's different.
How could I achieve this?

Thank you very much your help.

Comment: You could use `diff`, perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to sort the two files and run `comm` on the result.  If you have `bash` as your shell, you can use [Process Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution):

```
comm -3 <(sort a.unl) <(sort b.unl)
```

This will print all the lines in `a.unl` but not in `b.unl`, all the lines in `b.unl` but not in `a.unl` (they will be indented by a tab); the `-3` suppresses the lines in both `a.unl` and `b.unl`.

If you don't have `bash`, you probably need something like:

```
sort a.unl > a.srt
sort b.unl > b.srt
comm -3 a.srt b.srt
rm -f a.srt b.srt
```

To make that more nearly bombproof (so it doesn't leave intermediate files around if you interrupt things), then you need:

```
tmp=tmp.$$
trap "rm -f $tmp.?; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15

sort a.unl > $tmp.a
sort b.unl > $tmp.b
comm -3 $tmp.a $tmp.b

rm -f $tmp.?
trap 0
```

Comment: Thanks, this really works. Btw, I use comm -13 and "sort a.unl -o a.unl" so I don't have unnecessary file lying around.

Answer (score 4):

use `diff` to show difference between two files.

```
diff -u a.unl b.unl
```

Output looks like:

```
--- a.unl       2013-11-15 13:51:00.936845493 +0800
+++ b.unl       2013-11-15 13:51:21.373908098 +0800
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
+200032
+400042
 300111
-302130
-300042
-300054
-400045
+565000
+310056
```

`-` means delete from a.unl, `+` means add to a.unl.
use `man diff` to get more details.